# Puppet error: "Could not retrieve local facts: 404 Not Found"

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, puppet

I'm running Puppet version 0.25.4 from Ubuntu 10.04.
When I run:

```
puppetd --test
```

on one machine, this is the error I get:

```
err: Could not run Puppet configuration client: Could not retrieve local facts: 404 Not Found
```

I am able to "sign" the machine certificate from my master, but after that, nothing more.
Running the same version of Puppet on another machine, with the same configuration, works without any problem.

Even passing:

```
--debug --verbose
```

as command line arguments doesn't give me more clues.
Any ideas?

= Update to add more context =

This is the puppet.conf file I have on all the machines:

```
[main]
logdir = /var/log/puppet
vardir = /var/lib/puppet
ssldir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir = /var/run/puppet
factpath = $vardir/lib/facter
pluginsync = false
templatedir = $confdir/templates
prerun_command = /etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command = /etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[puppetd]
server = puppet
report = true
```

This is the output of running

```
puppetd --debug --verbose --test
```

from the error-machine:

```
debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roleadd does not exist
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/run/puppet/puppetd.pid]: Autorequiring File[/var/run/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/puppet.conf]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/HOSTNAME.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/HOSTNAME.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/HOSTNAME.pem]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
debug: Finishing transaction -613406248 with 0 changes
debug: Using cached certificate for ca, good until Tue Nov 22 13:59:42 UTC 2016
debug: Using cached certificate for HOSTNAME, good until Sat Nov 26 11:31:35 UTC 2016
debug: Executing '/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre'
debug: Executing '/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post'
err: Could not run Puppet configuration client: Could not retrieve local facts: 404 Not Found
```

and is basically the same of the other machines, apart from the fact that this does not do anything after executing etckeeper-commit-pre (and etckeeper is not installed in any machines).

Comment: So your client 'submits' facts as a GET request to the server and I believe it stores it in a file somewhere in /var/lib/puppet/yaml/facts/hostname.yaml ... does such a file exist for the client? I'd be more interested in the puppet master logs ... run it in the foreground in debug mode and see what it says.

Comment: The "facts" file for the machine that gives the error does not exists.
The cool part is that the server doesn't print anything if started in the foreground when I try to launch `puppetd --test` from the client. The error looks like is on the "local" (client) side of things.

Comment: The error is remote '404 Not Found' ... thats a HTTP error - check your HTTP logs to confirm if its even connecting to that web server (and you see the 404 on the server). Did you run the puppet master using --debug when it was in the foreground?

Comment: Master is running with `--verbose --debug`. I'm checking puppet log at `masterhttp.log` and could see only information from the client that has always been working, but nothing from the one that gives the error. I just tested opening all the doors on the firewall on the error-machine, but nothing changed. On the master I do not see any 404 error.

Comment: Hrm. What is in your puppet.conf? Its making a HTTP request 'somewhere/somehow' which is strange - do you get at least HTTP requests during this period from the client to the master? This is a terrible interface (stackoverflow that is) for debugging this kind of problem as it doesn't work with backwards/forwards questions very well :-). Maybe jump onto puppet-users on google groups ... and re-post there and we'll pick up the conversation :-).

Comment: I added some more context to the problem, the puppet.conf file and the output of the command from the evil-machine.
I will try to join the google group. Thanks for the assistance so far!

Comment: are you using root user?

Comment: Yes, the commands are executed with root.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually caused by Facter trying to contact an Amazon cloud service to get facts on the running virtual instance.

Obviously you don't have this running inside a cloud, so you don't need that.

Remove the following file:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/facter/ec2.rb
```

I moved mine out of that directory just in case I need it.  Renaming the file won't do the job.

Note, this is fixed in a later Puppet release.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Am not able to test at the moment, but will do!

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem.I try many times and didn't work.Then I use:

```
which -a puppet
```

And I find there are two puppet versions installed!
I remove all of them and then reinstall the puppet using deb packages and now it works.